# Icons of apps run from terminal

Tags: debian, icons

I recently moved to linux and am currently running Debian 8.2 stretch.
I have a question regarding the icons of apps that are executed from the terminal window.
My case in particular is with Emacs, I have a desktop launcher for emacs24 that has a high resolution icon. The problem is that am using a bash script to run emacsclient if a server is present and start the server first if not.
I noticed that even if I make a custom launcher for the script with a specific icon, the icon I have when switching apps with alt+tab is a low resolution version of the emacs icon.

I also tried running directly emacs24 from the terminal with
    `emacs &`
instead of using the default launcher and I also get the low resolution icon.

My question is: is there a way to control the icon that are used for apps when they are run from the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps: window managers *can* treat things specially by letting you associate a given icon with one of your desktop objects. Emacs has a preconfigured bitmap icon (which is not high-resolution).  According to the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Icons-X.html), you may use the `--no-bitmap-icon`  option to allow the window manager to choose its own icon.

Applications tell the window manager which icon they would like by setting the corresponding *window manager hint*, e.g., for the icon pixmap.  You can read more about that:

- [14.1.6 Setting and Reading the WM_HINTS Property](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/ICC/client-to-window-manager/wm-hints.html) (Xlib Programming Manual)
- [4. Client to Window Manager Communication](https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-4.html) (ICCCM)
- [Extended Window Manager Hints](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html)

While it seems that it could be possible to set the icon pixmap hint after creating a window, in practice [`wmctrl`](https://sites.google.com/site/tstyblo/wmctrl/) (a likely possibility) does not appear to do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply!
I didn't expect this thing to be complicated!
I tried the `--no-bitmap-icon` but the results is just a rectangle with emacs written on it.
I will try to look at some of the documentation you provided